# How can i write test Suite for Multiple Cest or Cept files...?

Tags: codeception

Well I'm new to Codeception, code will be executed in single file correctly but how am supposed to execute all files in a single test suite for Cest or Cept format php files.

Answer (score 1):

To execute all Cept and Cest files in test suite (e.g. defined in yourSuite.suite.yml) run

```
codecept run yourSuite
```

To execute particular Cept/Cest file run

```
codecept run path/to/your/testCept.php
```

To execute particular test of Cest class (public method of Cest class, e.g. TryToTest()) run

```
codecept run path/ti/yout/testCest.php:tryToTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply run it
`php codecept.phar run suite`

e.g. `php codecept.phar run unit`